# Disable other menu items when one of the menu item is clicked c#

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I have a simple menu in a WPF Client C# application where the user should be able to select only one item at a time. If one of the items is selected, the other items should be disabled until the operation is completed.

For example, I have the following menu

```
 <MenuItem Header="Help">
            <Separator></Separator>
            <MenuItem Header="User Manual.." Click="UsageDocMenuItem_Click" />
            <Separator></Separator>
            <MenuItem Header="Login"  Click="LoginItem_Click"/>
            <Separator></Separator>
            <MenuItem Header="About"  Click="AboutMenuItem_Click"/>
            <Separator></Separator>
        </MenuItem>`
```

If user clicks Login, User manual and About should be disabled until the operation trigerred by Login is finished.

Which C# design or code method can be used to implement this?

Comment: You will have to show us some of your code, it is impossible to help you with this information.

Comment: which technology? WInforms/WPF what else?

Comment: The technology is WPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I am not sure if we can use IDs of selected menu item since I want to disable the whole menu at once. I can so something like this:

```
<MenuItem Header="Help" Name="help">
        <Separator></Separator>
        <MenuItem Header="User Manual.."  Click="UsageDocMenuItem_Click" />
        <Separator></Separator>
        <MenuItem Header="Login"  Click="LoginItem_Click"/>
        <Separator></Separator>
        <MenuItem Header="About"  Click="AboutMenuItem_Click"/>
        <Separator></Separator>
    </MenuItem>`

void UsageDocMenuItem_Click()
{
    help.IsEnabled = false;
    //Do stuff
    help.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

By giving a name to the menu item, I can access it anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 1):

So means there are menu items and when User clicks on one of them for example : Login
Then till the time action is completed Login should be enabled and other menu items should be disabled.

You need to create an event of button click and within the same you need to write the code to find the other menu items and disable them.

```
Button_click Event(...)
{
//...disable other menu items
}
```

Comment: Yes you understood my question correctly. I already have events for each button click as shown in the code snippet above. I just need to know how to access the other menu items?

Comment: Web application or window?

Comment: Windows WPF application

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using 'WPF', you can use commands and your ViewModel that contains these commands to determine whether the command is enabled or not. This way it is also your ViewModel that knows the 'mode' you are in.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very detailed. If all you need is the basic logic/concept, then perhaps all you need is a method like this?:

```
public void DisableAllButOneMenuItem(int idOfSelectedMenuItem)
{
    // Code that disables all itmes, 
    // then code that enables a single item again.
}
```

Comment: I have added more details to my question now. Can you tell me how to get the ID of selected menu item and access its parent item in the code considering I have created a 'Click' event for each menu item?